# How do I contrast code for a factor where one level is the application of both of two others?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, contrasts

I have a factor 'Music' that has four levels: none, piano, guitar, and mixed. Subjects gave a response hearing no music, piano only, guitar only, or piano and guitar, so I want to create an lmer model `Response ~ Music + (1 | PersonID)`.

```
contrasts(Music)
```

gives me:

```
         Piano Guitar Mixed
None      0     0    0
Piano     1     0    0
Guitar    0     1    0
Mixed     0     0    1
```

but I feel there should be some indication that Mixed is actually the application  of both piano and guitar.

My question is:

Should I indicate the link between the levels? Do I do it by contrast coding? How?

I tried `contrasts(Music) <- cbind( 1, c(0,1,0,1), c(0,0,1,1), c(0,0,0,1) )` as @Greg Snow suggested and got

`contrasts(Music)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
None    1    0    0
Piano   1    1    0
Guitar  1    0    1
Mixed   1    1    1`

But this gives an error `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient`

Comment: Where you write "is actually the sum of," does that mean you expect the coefficient of `Mixed` in this model to be the sum of the coefficients of `Piano` and `Guitar`?

Comment: whuber, I've amended the question. I expect Mixed to have a greater effect than the sum of its parts. Thank you.

Comment: If I correctly understand what you intend, you can either have a "no-piano/piano" and a "no-guitar/guitar" factor, and pick up "mixed" via an interaction term, *or* you can have a single factor with "none/piano/guitar/mixed".

Comment: Thanks Glen_b. What are the advantages/disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 1):

With the current/default contrasts the coefficients will represent the difference between the baseline of "None" with each of the other levels.

There are a couple of options, the first is to recode as 2 factors with Piano being Yes/No and Guitar being Yes/No, then fit the 2 factors and their interaction.

Another option is to set a different set of contrasts (really a dummy variable encoding).  You can use the assignment form of the `contrasts` function to do this:

```
contrasts(Music) <- cbind( 1, c(0,1,0,1), c(0,0,1,1), c(0,0,0,1) )
```

and then the coefficients will represent the same idea as splitting and including the interaction, i.e. the 3rd coefficient will represent the difference from the additive model.